# How to slow down sensivity of grabbing objects via the user preferences

Tags: 3d-view, customization

I would like to slow down the sensitivity of the Grab function (<kbd>G</kbd>) in Blender. Is there a way to do that permanently, not just with holding down <kbd>Shift</kbd> or changing the scene scale?

Comment: It often can be fixed by changing Pivot Point. If it's set to 3D Cursor, grabbing / moving objects can be faster depending on whether cursor is far away or not.

Comment: You can alter the scale for the viewport (or the scene)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is no way to scale down the cursor speed in Blender when grabbing, 
*(aside from holding shift as you've mentioned)*.